# Split a string with separators to be stored in an array

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how to split a string with each separator, I've split strings before only I can't remember how to put separator in place. For my program i have to import data and have a bar chart generated from the imported values. The data includes data including company names which obviously may not be 1 word long, and so there are commas in place to separate each 'column'. Here is an example of a line of data:

> 565800,22796,PHOTO FRAME 3 CLASSIC HANGING,4,07/09/2011 10:23,9.95,14911

Once split I will need to store them in an array for the values to be called on to create the bar chart.

Comment: Have you tried `string.Split`?

Comment: Use a library that can handle CSV files (f.i. https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/ ). Read the https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180 to understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) method which allows you to specify the separator that you would like to split by and then it will return an array of strings that are separated by the delimiter:

```
string s = "565800,22796,PHOTO FRAME 3 CLASSIC HANGING,4,07/09/2011 10:23,9.95,14911";
string[] parts = s.Split(',');
```

There are also [`various overloads`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) of this method that you might take a look.

Comment: There are many more lines of data, how would I get it to read one line, obviously i'd put a loop in afterwards. Can streamreader be used for textboxes or is that just external data sources

Comment: Yes, you could use a `StreamReader` if the file is very large. If it is small and the contents can fit in memory you could use this: `string[] lines = File.readAllLines("myFile.csv");` which will read all the lines into an array of string in memory. If on the other hand the file is too big to fit in memory you could read it line by line using a simple `StreamReader`.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is very big, you can use [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. This will enumerate the lines from the source file instead of reading them all into a single potentially massive array:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("path/to/file.txt"))
{
    string[] split = line.Split(',');
}
```